# Object.forEach in filter function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using `Discord.js` to write a Discord bot in this project. I am trying to put a ReactionCollector on a message and check if the reaction used is inside my data.

The data is stored in this config.json

```
{
  "botId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "emojis": {
    "classes": [{
      "one": "716821724884238506",
      "two": "716821724863266876",
      "three": "716821724884369488"
    }]
  }
}
```

This is the filter I want to assign to the ReactionController. It should trigger if the found reaction is inside the config.json and is not written by the bot itself.

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {

  if(user.id === CONFIG.botId) {
    return false;
  }

  CONFIG.emojis.classes.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(value === reaction.emoji.id) {
        console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`)
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And finally the collector i want to use the filter in:

```
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter);
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`Collected: ${reaction.emoji.id}`);
  let alreadySetClass = '';
  if (message.channel.name.includes(reaction.emoji.name.toLowerCase())) {
    alreadySetClass = reaction.emoji.name.toLowerCase()
  }

  console.log("setClass: " + alreadySetClass)
  setChannelName(message.channel, reaction.emoji.name, alreadySetClass)

})
```

The response i get by collecting the reaction is a [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) object.

The consol.log of the filter will print the key, value pair correctly. But the `console.log('collected: ')` inside the collector won't execute at all. There are no errors in the console. I don't know what I'm missing here. I think there is something wrong with the way I wrote the filter. Some help would be awesome. Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your data, which you are getting and trying to perform action on it

Comment: I added the object im getting as a link to the doc of discord.js. It is a MessageReaction object.

Comment: @Frossy I think you should move the condition `user.id !== CONFIG.botId` outside the nested for loop. That condition is separated from emoji ID condition.

Comment: @NguyễnViệtĐức i did try putting it before the forEach and returned false if the user.id === CONFIG.botId The result didnt change if thats what you are talking about

Comment: Yeah, it won't change the result. That's why I commented instead of answering. But if you look closely, for each class inside the object, you have to check `botId` again, even though they are the same.

Comment: That is very true, i updated the posted code and my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in your filter you're returning `true` from the callback of the `forEach` method: that means that the callback will return true, but your filter won't receive any return and so will return `undefined`, which is interpreted as `false` (and so won't collect any reaction).
Instead of `forEach`, try using the [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method: if any of the callbacks return `true` for one element, the method will return `true`.

Here's how I would do it:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  // Check if the id is different and if for any of the classes ...
  return user.id != CONFIG.botId && CONFIG.emojis.classes.some(obj => {
    // ... at least one entry ...
    return Object.entries(obj).some(([key, value]) => {
      // ... has a value that matches the emoji id
      if (value == reaction.emoji.id) {
        console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`)
        // If so, return true
        return true
      }
    })
  })
}
```

PS: I know there's a lot of nested functions and it's not the most readable code, but it should do the trick.

Comment: This of course works perfectly fine. I mad an absolute newbie mistake right there. Thanks alot for the quick help.